# Code for playing video in wx.Media after the wmv file is loaded

Tags: python

I am a newbie in wxPython and I have to write a code that can immediately start playing a video after I load the file. I have been going through a lot of forums tried to implement 10 - 20 codes, but the wx.media is not playing the video file at all. I am able to load the file but not play it.

I need a simple code in which I will manually enter the path name of the video file and after this file is loaded it should start playing.

I am using windows XP, Python 2.7 and wxPython for Python 2.7.

I would be very grateful to all of you if you could help me on this one.

Following is the code that I am using to **load()** and then **play()** the file. Still it is not working.

```
import wx 
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

        # Create some controls
        try:
            self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.Destroy()
            raise
        self.mc.Load(r"C:\Documents and Settings\N1002401B\Desktop\test1.wmv")
        #self.slider.SetRange(0, self.mc.Length())
        #folder, filename = os.path.split("C:\Documents and Settings\N1002401B\Desktop\test1.wmv")
        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.OnPlay)
    def OnPlay(self,evt):
        self.mc.Play()

app = wx.App(0)

frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = TestPanel(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial for the wx.media module [here](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/media/wx.media.html).

You have to call `Load(path)` and `Play()` on your `MediaCtrl` object.

It would be a good idea for future posts to include a small snippet of your code, so that we can know what exactly you have tried.

Comment: I have added my piece of code in the question. Can you tell me what is wrong in the code and why is it that I am not getting any error but still you cannot see the wmv files being played?

Comment: I have modified my code. Now I am able to play the sound but the video does not come up in the background.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Maybe you are using a bogus video format? Try it with another video, especially when you can hear the sound but cannot see the video.

Comment: Now my code works. I added this replaced self.mc with the following line.self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)