# How To Make Sound Play In Python

Tags: python, audio

How would I be able to play a `.wma` file in Python?  Let's just say the file name is `Scream.wma`

Comment: See [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674442/code-for-playing-video-in-wx-media-after-the-wmv-file-is-loaded)

Comment: `.wmv` stands for Windows Media _Video_.

Comment: Sorry meant the sound file

Comment: Sorry to be picky... Cannot parse "meant the sound file". If the file name is `scream.wmv`, it is a video file. Is the name `scream.wav`?

Comment: Yes it is an audio file.  Sorry again. :

Comment: A simple google search *"play sound in python"* was enough for this question.

Comment: google is your friend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftQ6A3DKKeg

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/ has a long list of audio libraries. There's even one on the list called wave, which is just for WAV files. Besides those you can use PyGame:

```
import pygame
import pygame.mixer
pygame.mixer.music.load('file.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```